# How to start a remote machine process that requires Command Line Arguments with WMI component

Tags: c#, vb.net, wmi

I am planning to use WMI to start a process on a remote machine(say batch process). But the process was designed to start with Command Line Argument (say Batch_Type_Code). I couldn't find any sample that uses command line arguments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389388%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for `Win32_Process.Create`, the command line argument includes both the path to the executable and the arguments:

```
Create("\"%SYSTEMROOT%\\system32\\cmd.exe\" /K \"echo multiple spaces here\"", null, null, null);
```

Comment: Yeap, that is how it worked. Thanks. Just realized that I can't up vote ur answer, I haven't enough reputation :P

Comment: @Milla, If this solved your problem, you can mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the check-mark beneath the upvote button.