# WMI StartService Parameter

Tags: service, windows-services, wmi

I am currently starting a Service in my C# code using WMI, and I would like to set its startup parameters.

Is there a way to do this? I couldn't find anything relevant so far.

Thanks in advance.

Thomas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These other posts helped me to solve my issue :

> https://superuser.com/questions/809868/wmi-startservice-parameter
>
> [Dynamics AX 2012 RegConfig does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466035/dynamics-ax-2012-regconfig-does-not-work)

Answer (score 0):

Check the open source project

[Services+](http://servicesplus.codeplex.com/)

Contains full usage of WMI with StartService

Example VB.Net:

```
Dim objPath = "\\ComputerName\root\cimv2:Win32_Service.Name='ServiceName'"
Using objService As New ManagementObject(objPath)
   Dim outParams = objService.InvokeMethod("StartService", Nothing)
   rtnVal.WmiValue = CInt(outParams)
End Using
```

Comment: Yes, and after a lot of investigation it appeared that it is not possible to send parameters at start of a service using WMI.
Look my answer to see (second link) to see the solution I adopted.

Answer (score 0):

For history:

Hi!

You need to connect to a remote machine using WMI class Win32_Process.

Then you need to run a local command for the remote computer, for example "sc.exe start Spooler arg1"
[How to start a remote machine process that requires Command Line Arguments with WMI component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055638/how-to-start-a-remote-machine-process-that-requires-command-line-arguments-with)

p.s. additional DACL security settings may be required "sc.exe sdshow spooler"

p.p.s. WMI and SC work via RPC, so it's better to use the method "Start" of the class "ServiceController"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.start?view=netframework-4.7.2